# Should we clear chatty comments from election nominations?

Tags: discussion, comments, moderator-election

In past elections, and seemingly in this one too, we've seen 'real' questions for the nominees pushed below the fold by comments like this:

[image]

My instinct from the rest of the site is to clear these out to make room for comments with substance. Pros and cons I'm seeing:

- We've set a pretty solid precedent of not 'interfering' in elections. I agree with that.
- These comments can, and do, push 'real' ones (that ask nominees questions or express support *for a reason*) below the fold, making them less discoverable.
- We'd have to decide where to draw the line. I'd be in favor of removing *all* of the above comments - but would that be seen as removing support for a nominee?

Thoughts?

Comment: Since support in comments for a nominee has no effect in the nominations, why keep it?

Comment: It's a real shame that voting on comments was disabled on nomination statements. I know the problems with that (can't downvote bad comments, so they only can get upvotes, etc.), but at least it brought some useful comments up above the fold.

Comment: 10 upvotes in under a minute says that it's better. I also agree with culling of these comments. If the users want to show their support, they can do so using votes on the questionnaire instead.

Comment: The only comment I am concerned about deleting in the above set is the one from ankit suthar.  To me it reads more of a statement of support of the candidate then a simple good luck comment.  Maybe instead of deleting then we hide them and give a link to un-hide them?

Comment: @YvetteColomb I don't really see a reason we couldn't. We all have our ideas about who should win (like everyone else), but I tend to think we can be impartial about something like this. It'd likely manifest itself as "when we're reading comments, if there's a big block of chatty ones in the way we can clear them out"

Comment: Thought about that @NathanOliver. To me, it doesn't seem to contain any reason that isn't implied by a statement of 'good luck' - as Bhargav mentioned, it might be better placed as a vote on the questionnaire or when the election starts. It's the one I'm most borderline about, so if we wanted to draw the line there I'd be fine with it.

Comment: @Undo When you put it that way I see it now.  I guess they can all go then.  IMO the comment section should be for questions the users have for the candidates.  The Q&A is a good place for support.

Comment: It would be better to give the candidate the option of removing. Then it's in their hands to deal with comments and they themselves can choose how to handle them. If they choose to leave them and miss a comment that's their fault. If they delete all the comments and someone gets upset it comes back to them and them alone.

Comment: @Bugs, I don't think it should be up to the candidates. If someone has a complaint about me, I'd expect them to post it on there. Giving me the ability to *hide* a legitimate complaint does a disservice to everyone else looking at my nomination.

Comment: Hm yeah OK, maybe they have the ability to flag and allow a mod to decide. It would help those like Yvette who don't want their comments removed quite so quickly and those that are happy for them to be removed. I'd not want them removed if it was me, not so quickly anyway.

Comment: @Undo I don't have issue at all with deleting them, I do have issue with changing the policy mid-election.

Comment: If we've learned anything from other recent elections, it is that they should not be a mere popularity contest.

Comment: @CodyGray I couldn't agree more. My only issue with this is doing it mid election

Comment: At the very least we should change the placeholder text to provide some more relevant guidance to commenters. Right now, it's the one as in answer comments, don't know how useful that is for election comments.

Comment: Or don't allow comments at all and just use the meta post to ask further questions which _can_ be upvoted etc.

Comment: You *always* have to do it mid-election, @Yvette. That's when the comments are posted. I guess you're saying that the policy should have been announced in advance, before the nominations started? Maybe that would have been good, but I don't really see how it would have changed anything.

Comment: @CodyGray yeh of course we have to delete the comments mid election :)  - I mean if we're changing election policy we shouldn't do it mid-election. But it's not just up to me and I'm just being pedantic.

Comment: @Bugs people use the comments to help decide who to vote on

Comment: @YvetteColomb either way it wouldn't bother me to see all the comments under the meta post instead of the nomination post. I'm going to upvote the ones I think are helpful and ignore the ones that aren't. The ones that aren't can even be removed from the meta post if somebody wishes to flag it.

Comment: @Bugs true, I think it's a shame there's not more commenting under the meta posts, but many users aren't even aware of the meta posts, they just see the notice of election and browse the candidates. The majority of voters are not consummate users of meta like we are :D

Comment: @Brad Larson: Also, aside from the ideal of *no* vapid comments, I'd gladly take a single vapid comment with 100 upvotes than 100 vapid comments that cannot be upvoted filling up the entire comment space. This is why, when looking at a popular answer with many "thanks!" comments, I tend to delete all *but one* with the most upvotes, and pray that those upvoting that remaining comment haven't forgotten to also upvote the answer.

Answer (score 38):

While I think non-interference in elections is an important principle, I don't think removing noisy comments qualifies as interference.

I *absolutely* think this is something that moderators should do periodically, when the noise is crowding out relevant, meaningful comments. They should obviously do so carefully and judiciously, but that's no different than how they would exercise their privileges in any other context.

> I'd be in favor of removing all of the above comments - but would that be seen as removing support for a nominee?

Maybe, but so what? There is no point in showing support for a nominee. That's why we have the "primary" phase, where vote arrows will be added so that support can be expressed in a clear and sane manner.

Comment: Elections don't have vote arrows in the elections anymore. It's "First Choice", "Second Choice", and I seem to recall there being a "Third Choice" last year.

Comment: @Tiny Giant: Yeah, that's the final phase. Cody's referring to the primary phase, which precedes the election phase, and usually doesn't get skipped on SO because there tend to be enough candidates for the primary to run.

Comment: @BoltClock ahh I was mistaken. For some reason I remembered there being the same buttons in the primary phase last year.

Answer (score 21):

Yes, we should remove them. They're useless, and they can cause useful comments to be hidden or drowned in the noise.

Comment: Yeh I must admit, I was asked a couple of really good questions and it would be good to have more of those

Answer (score 11):

I largely agree with much of what everyone has said thus far - yes, remove the comments - but I want to call this specific line out:

> ...I'd be in favor of removing all of the above comments - but would that be seen as removing support for a nominee?

The only tangible support is that of a vote cast in either the primaries or in the election itself.  Merely *voicing* that support isn't "support" that can be measured, since it doesn't correlate to actual votes.

I wouldn't feel offended, upset, or even bat an eye if the "good luck"-style comments were removed to expose the heavier hitting, "So, I see you haven't done XYZ for the site, why should we consider you for moderator?"-style comments.